# Bottom sheet above the scrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, bottom-sheet

I want this kind of bottom sheet which should be above the ScrollView.

[image]

The images in the scroll view should be behind the bottom sheet. the bottom sheet should always be there on the screen till the proceed button on it is clicked. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: So how far you are to do this

Comment: I don't know how to do this !! @MilindVyas

Comment: Did you try to implement it as a card view?

Comment: ok let me clarify your  question if user will click proceed after that only scroll and other things works am i right ? and this will bottom sheet right?

Comment: @MalithLakshan yeah actually cardView worked !! I was thinking of implementing it through Bottom Sheet . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bottom sheet/panel is always there, theres no need to overlap those panels check this simplified xml layout example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is your root layout element -->
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:android_width="match_parent"
  android:android_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="4">

  <ScrollView
    android:android_width="match_parent"
    android:android_height="0dp">
    <!-- Put your inner grid layout here -->
  </ScrollView>


  <!-- this is your bottom panel layout -->
  <!-- you can control the size of your bottom -->
  <!--  pane by playing with the layout weights  -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
      android:text="Proceed"
      android:background="@drawable/yourSelectorXml"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's see the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:android_width="match_parent"
    android:android_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <ScrollView
        android:android_width="match_parent"
        android:android_height="0dp">
        <!-- Put your inner grid layout here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- put your bottom panel layout here -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:text="Proceed"
            android:background="@drawable/yourSelectorXml"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```